# How to replace a substring with help of preg_replace

Tags: php, regex

I have a string that consists of repeated words. I want to replace a substring 'OK' located between 'L3' and 'L4'. Below you can find my code:

```
$search = "/(?<=L3).*(OK).*(?=L4)/";
$replace = "REPLACEMENT";
$subject = "'L1' => ('Vanessa', 'Prague', 'OK'), 'L2' => ('Alex', 'Paris', 'OK'), 'L3' => ('Paul', 'Paris', 'OK'), 'L4' => ('John', 'Madrid', 'OK')";
$str = preg_replace($search, $replace, $str);
```

If I use that pattern with preg_match, it finds a correct substring(third 'OK'). However, when I apply that pattern to preg_replace, it replaces substring that matches the full pattern, instead of the parenthesized subpattern.

So could you please give me an advice what I should change in my code? I know that there are plenty amount of similar questions about regex, but as I understand my pattern is correct and I'm only confused with preg_replace function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is true that your regex matches a place in the string that is preceded with `L3` then contains the last `OK` substring after 0+ chars other than linebreak symbols and then matches any 0+ chars up to the place followed with `L4`. See [your regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fF3hB7/1).

A possible solution is to use  2 capturing groups  around the subpatterns before and after the `OK`, and use backreferences in the replacement pattern:

```
$search = "/(L3.*?)OK(.*?L4)/";
$replace = "REPLACEMENT";
$subject = "'L1' => ('Vanessa', 'Prague', 'OK'), 'L2' => ('Alex', 'Paris', 'OK'), 'L3' => ('Paul', 'Paris', 'OK'), 'L4' => ('John', 'Madrid', 'OK')";
$str = preg_replace($search, '$1'.$replace.'$2', $subject);
echo $str; // => 'L1' => ('Vanessa', 'Prague', 'OK'), 'L2' => ('Alex', 'Paris', 'OK'), 'L3' => ('Paul', 'Paris', 'REPLACEMENT'), 'L4' => ('John', 'Madrid', 'OK')
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/nma2FH)

If there cannot be any `L3.5` in between `L3` and `L4`, the `(L3.*?)OK(.*?L4)` pattern is safe to use. It will match and capture `L3` and then 0+ chars other than a linebreak up to the first `OK`, then will match `OK`, and then will match and capture 0+ chars up to the first `L4`.

If there can be no `L4`, use a `(?:(?!L4).)*` tempered greedy token matching any symbol other than a linebreak symbol that is not starting an `L4` sequence:

```
'~(L3(?:(?!L4).)*)OK~'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oB6gW1/1)

**NOTE**: If you want to make the regexps safer, add `'` around `L#` inside the patterns.